# How to check for missing values as a condition for a function

Tags: python, pandas

can anyone help me fix this condition
I have a column in my dataframe that I want to recode into different values. I just started with Pandas and i'm a bit more confident with functions so I want to use a function that I can map/apply on that column. Most of the script is working as intended. but I can't seem to find the right syntax for the missing value check in this function.

```
    This is how the dataframe looks.

       Thiscolumn   Question1   Question2
    0   NaN          Q1R0         Q2R0
    1   Word1        Q1R1         Q2R1
    2   NaN          Q1R2         Q2R2
    3   Word2        Q1R3         Q2R3
    4   Word3        Q1R4         Q2R4
    5   Word4        Q1R5         Q2R5
```

I have written the function and the map/apply method but I keep getting an error in the missing value check.

```
def Recoder(column):
    if column =="Word1":
        return "A"
    elif column =="Word2":
        return "B"
    elif column.isna():
        return "Word is missing"
    else :
        return "D"


df["Thiscolumn"]=df["Thiscolumn"].map(Recoder)
```

This part of the function i can't seem to find (probably because isna() is an method of a Pandas Dataframe and i'm only giving it 1 argument

```
elif column.isna():
        return "Word is missing"
```

Can someone help me find a solution for both these problems

1. The condition required here to check during mapping/applying that the value is NaN
   I have tried .hasnas / .isnull / .isna    (Fix for this problem)
2. A way to insert a panda dataframe as an ag a function. So I can use the .isna() on it   (A more robust solution for future functions)

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely want these lines to be:

```
elif pands.isna(column):
   return "Word is missing"
```

Comment: Indeed, thank you that works perfectly
.
Quick question what would be the method be for passing in a df as the argument of the function (feels like i will need it in the future)